# Override JSF value expressions set in XHTML

Tags: jsf-2, el, icefaces

In one of my JSF (IceFaces 3) projects I need to implement a solution for controlling the appearance of components via XML. I managed to create something that is at least partially working: A SystemEventListener implementation is responsible for setting a component's 'disabled' and 'rendered' attributes according to the set configuration. However, these attributes can be set (with valueExpressions) in the XHTML too, in which case the component will be rendered with those values. The processing of these valueExpressions is always comes after the PreRenderComponentEvent, making my solution useless.
I'm curious: Is there any way I can ovverride or alter the valueExpressions set in the XHTML?

Comment: >>Is there any way I can ovverride or alter the valueExpressions set in the XHTML?: **Yes**. The rest of your question is unclear. Are you unable to listen to the prerendercomponent event?

Comment: I'm able to listen to the event, and e.g. I can disable the specific component by calling `setDisabled(true)`, or by setting the valueExpression. But If the disabled attribute is set to a backing bean method's return value via EL in the XHTML, the component will be validated with that value. No matter what I do in my listener, handling any type of ComponentSystemEvent.